# How to install PHPEclipse

Tags: php, eclipse, ide

I installed Eclipse 3.7.1 on Windows 7, and followed this [guide](http://www.phpeclipse.com/wiki/Installation).

The error that eclipse shows is:

> Unable to read repository at
>   http://update.phpeclipse.com/update/stable/1.2.x. Unable to read
>   repository at http://update.phpeclipse.com/update/stable/1.2.x.
>   http://update.phpeclipse.com/update/stable/1.2.x is not a valid
>   repository location.

Comment: Please provide OS info :) Windows? Linux? Distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just want to update the link of `PHPEclipse` download site. New download site is http://update.phpeclipse.com/update/stable/1.2.x for PHPEclipse Stable Builds. You can view the information [here](http://www.phpeclipse.com/wiki/Installation) on how to install PHPEclipse.

To make sure update site is still available, test the connection first.

```
$ ping update.phpeclipse.com
```

```
PING phpeclipse.com (74.93.86.171): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 74.93.86.171: icmp_seq=0 ttl=46 time=242.241 ms
64 bytes from 74.93.86.171: icmp_seq=1 ttl=46 time=288.094 ms
64 bytes from 74.93.86.171: icmp_seq=2 ttl=46 time=329.756 ms
```

As of this moment, updates from phpeclipse.net is inaccessible.

```
$ ping update.phpeclipse.net
```

```
PING update.phpeclipse.net (209.251.121.171): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
```

I've used the above update site to add phpeclipse plugin for my Flash Builder 4.6.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the [PHPEclipse plugin page](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/phpeclipse?mpc=true&mpc_state=) You can see the correct URL ends in `.net`

The tutorial mistyped it. Alternatively you could have just searched for the plugin in the eclipse marketplace.

The direct Link:

http://phpeclipse.sourceforge.net/update/stable/1.2.x/

Comment: Its not working for me. Both links http://phpeclipse.sourceforge.net/update/stable/1.2.x/ or http://update.phpeclipse.net/update/stable/1.2.x are unable to read repo. I can browse to the first one however.

Comment: @Dejan Did you try using the market? That is by far the easiest way.

Comment: The link in the market is http://update.phpeclipse.net/update/stable/1.2.x which fails with error `HTTP Server Unknown HTTP Response Code (-1)`